# Excel .find Macro to write data to archive

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to speed up this piece of code. The macro gets a search variable from the worksheet `"RAW_DATA_ARCHIVE"` and then it should find it in the worksheet `"RAW DATA"`. When it finds accordance then the value of column A from worksheet `"RAW DATA"` will be written in the last column of `"RAW_DATA_ARCHIVE"`.

```
 For i = 2 To ws1LRow
    SearchString = ws1.Range("A" & i).Value
    Set aCell = ws2.Columns(5).Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    'If match found
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        ws1.Cells(i, 80).Value = ws2.Cells(aCell.Row, 1).Value

    End If
Next
```

Comment: You don't need a VBA macro to do this. Have you seen what `VLOOKUP` can do for you? Try something like this in column 80 of sheet Raw_Data_Archive: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'RAW DATA'!E:E,1,FALSE),"")`

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly what you're doing, then VBA is simply not the right tool for this task. Excel has a built-in `VLOOKUP` function specifically for this purpose - try something like this in column 80 of the `RAW_DATA_ARCHIVE` sheet:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'RAW DATA'!E:E,1,FALSE),"")
```

---

That said, you *did* post some VBA code, albeit just a loop. Here are some thoughts, mostly on naming style:

- `ws1` and `ws2` would probably be better off as `sourceSheet` and `targetSheet`.
- `ws1LRow` would be more meaningful as simply `lastRow`
- `i` is usually fine as a loop counter, but here it has a clear meaning: `targetRow`
- `aCell` is really a `searchResult`

Using such meaningful names instantly makes it easier to read the code, which makes it easier to maintain/modify without breaking anything.

It also eliminates the need for explanatory comments:

> ```
> 'If match found
> If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
> ```

vs.

```
If Not searchResult Is Nothing Then
```

---

A number of things explain why your code is slow.

1. You're using procedural code instead of built-in worksheet functions
2. You're writing to cells in a loop, *presumably* with `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`, which means many things happen every time you write a value into a cell.

Comment: Firstly the target sheet get replaced every week, so i need vba. Besides the `"vloockup"` doesn't help me, because my target value is on the left side of the search value.

Comment: Had you answered to my comment 4 days ago my answer might have been different. I see you're using index+match here.... well, use that instead of a vlookup and you'll save yourself 10 minutes of looping.`WorksheetFunction` is calling, well, the worksheet functions after all - only much, much slower.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I found the `"Index-Match"` functions. It is a little bit faster but also take over 10 minutes for about 160000 Cells. Meanwhile, I think it's too much data to get it faster.

```
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each searchCell In searchRange
        targetSheet.Cells(searchCell.Row, 80) = .Index(sourceSheet.Columns(1), .Match(searchCell.Value, sourceSheet.Columns(2), 0))
    Next
End With
```